# Create Custom shaped buttons in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and not sure how to work around with this.

I wanted to design a custom view which I want to have buttons in the shape of an circle.(Screenshot attached) [image]

I was able to do it by using layers and adding the layers using the following :

```
// radius is the half the frame's width or height (whichever is smallest)
        let radius = min(frame.size.width, frame.size.height) * 0.5

        // center of the view
        let viewCenter = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * 0.5, y: bounds.size.height * 0.5)

        // enumerate the total value of the segments by using reduce to sum them
        var valueCount = outerSegments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})

        var startAngle : CGFloat = 0
        var i = 0
       // var data: [String] = ["","","","","","","","","","","",""]
        for segment in outerSegments { // loop through the values array
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i]
            //addText(data[i], to: shape)
            layer.addSublayer(shape)
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
        valueCount = innerSegments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})
        startAngle = 0
        i = 100
        for segment in innerSegments {
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: 2*radius/3, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            //datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i-100]
            //addText(data[i-100], to: shape)
            layer.addSublayer(shape)
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
        valueCount = innerMostSegments.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value})
        startAngle = 0
        i = 1000
        for segment in innerMostSegments {
            let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
            let shape = CAShapeLayer()
            let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius/3, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
            path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
            path.close()
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.borderWidth = 1.0
            shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            shape.name = "\(i)"
            datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i-1000]
            //addText(data[i-1000], to: shape)
            layer.addSublayer(shape)
            startAngle = endAngle
            i += 1
        }
```

This works perfectly fine but I want to work with the same shape but instead of using the layer, I want to define Buttons instead of the layers in the view.  If I try to add the UIButton directly, the screen isn't tappable anymore.

Can anyone advise with the same.

Thanks

EDIT - I tried to add button using the following strategy :

```
for segment in innerSegments {
    let endAngle = startAngle + 2 * .pi * (segment.value / valueCount)
                let shape = CAShapeLayer()
                let button = UIButton(frame: accessibilityFrame)
                let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: viewCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
                path.addLine(to: viewCenter)
                path.close()
                shape.path = path.cgPath
                shape.fillColor = segment.color.cgColor
                shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                shape.borderWidth = 1.0
                shape.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                shape.name = "\(i)"
                datamap[shape.name ?? ""] = data[i]
                //addText(data[i], to: shape)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
                button.layer.addSublayer(shape)
                layer.addSublayer(button.layer)

                startAngle = endAngle
                i += 1
```

.
.
.

Comment: @matt My apologies, added the code in the edit

Comment: @matt As I said, I am new to this and learning, It would be great if you could provide the pointers to the same.

Comment: @matt I tried it and still the buttons were not tappable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214597/discussion-between-dper-and-matt).